# how to render output of wordcloud2 in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

How can I make sure that the output of `wordcloud2::wordcloud2()` appears in my RMarkdown (HTML) document?

It renders fine in RStudio, including in the preview of the RMarkdown document, but when I upload it to my netlify site with blogdown, it doesn't show (see [here](https://robertmylesmcdonnell.netlify.com/2017/09/07/lil-packages-pt-1/), bottom of the post). Any ideas?

Edit: here's the code I'm using. Like I said, it works perfectly in RStudio, just not on the website itself.

```
library(tidyRSS)

five38 <- tidyfeed("http://fivethirtyeight.com/all/feed")
library(wordcloud2)

topics <- five38$item_category1 %>% append(five38$item_category2) %>% 
  append(five38$item_category3) %>% 
  append(five38$item_category4) %>% 
  append(five38$item_category5)

Topics <- data_frame(
  words = topics
) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(words)) %>% 
  group_by(words) %>% 
  tally()

wordcloud2(Topics)
```

Comment: Please provide a small Rmd with `wordcloud2` example which doesn't render properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

````
```{r}
library(htmlwidgets)
install.packages("webshot")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
library(wordcloud2)
hw = wordcloud2(demoFreq,size = 3)
saveWidget(hw,"1.html",selfcontained = F)
webshot::webshot("1.html","1.png",vwidth = 700, vheight = 500, delay =10)
```
![](1.png)
````

ok, i found this way to solve this problem from the author of wordcloud2.